# Use of semicolons with if/else and try/finally blocks

Tags: delphi

I have found that this code compiles both with and without a semicolon at the places pointed out below.

What is the correct way to use semicolons here?

```
  try
    try
      if MyBoolean = True then
      begin
        DoSomething;
      end
      else
      begin
        DoSomethingElse;
      end <<<--- Semi colon here?
    except
      ;
    end <<<--- Semi colon here?
  finally
    ;
  end;
```

Comment: You can do as you like; there's no "right" or "wrong". The program is the same in both cases (with or without the semicolon). I think Qs similar to this one has been asked many times. Here's one related Q: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7574603/why-do-single-statement-blocks-require-not-using-semi-colons

Comment: Good. I was worried about possible unexpected behaviour in case of exceptions.

Comment: No. But there are a small number of situations where the semicolon becomes surprisingly important. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7575138/282848) the most famous example.

Comment: It's like in CSS: semicolons are needed to **separate**, not to finalize. If it is logically separated already then it isn't needed... or (again: like in CSS) more specifically: you're making an empty command. Just like writing `;;;;;` is totally okay the optional semicolons are disregarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is documented behavior:

[Declarations and Statements (Delphi): Compound Statements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#Compound_Statements)

> A compound statement is a sequence of other (simple or structured) statements to be executed in the order in which they are written. The compound statement is bracketed by the reserved words `begin` and `end`, and its constituent statements are separated by semicolons. For example:
>
> ```
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   X := Y;
> end;
> ```
>
> **The last semicolon before `end` is optional.** So this could have been written as:
>
> ```
> begin
>   Z := X;
>   X := Y;
>   Y := Z
> end;
> ```

And also:

[Delphi's Object Pascal Style Guide: Statements](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Delphi_Statements)

> Statements are one or more lines of code followed by a semicolon. Simple statements have one semicolon, while compound statements have more than one semicolon and therefore consist of multiple simple statements.
>
> Here is a simple statement:
>
> ```
> A := B;
> ```
>
> If you need to wrap the simple statement, indent the second line two spaces in from the previous line. Here is a compound, or structured, statement:
>
> ```
> begin
>   B := C;
>   A := B;
> end;
> ```
>
> Compound Statements always end with a semicolon, **unless they immediately precede an end keyword, in which case the semicolon is optional** but recommended by this style guide.

An "end keyword" in your example would include `except` and `finally`.

Comment: That description is surprisingly poor. (That's Embarcadero's fault, not Remy's! Oh, I see this is from the Style Guide, not the "real" language documentation.)

Comment: One problem with the quoted text is that it claims that every simple statement ends with a semicolon. But this clearly doesn't work in `if P then DoThis else DoThat` where `DoThis` is a statement which absolutely *mustn't* end with a semicolon. There are other issues as well.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I didn't quote the entire spec, but your point is covered in [`If Statements`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements_(Delphi)#If_Statements): "*Notice that a semicolon between the `then` clause and the word `else` is never used. You can place a semicolon after an entire `if` statement to separate it from the next statement in its block, but the `then` and `else` clauses require nothing more than a space or carriage return between them. Placing a semicolon immediately before `else` (in an `if` statement) is a common programming error.*"

Comment: Also, "Compound Statements always end with a semicolon". This means that there is a semicolon after the four-line compound statement: `end;`. But this -- and the exception -- also applies to "simple statements". I almost get the feeling that the intended phrasing is "Each individual statement in a compound statement ends with a semicolon...". Technical documentation shouldn't be this imprecise!

Comment: Sure, the official language documentation is good, but the Style Guide quote isn't.

Comment: (Or maybe mathematically-inclined people like me should just stop complaining about statements that are technically incorrect but cause little harm in practice...)